# Having only once the field in odoo table

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have a column "Untaxed Amount" and I want to have only 1 value of "price" field,because it' a total price for all articles, but I'm getting this value for each article. How is it possible to have only 1 iteration of that value in .xml vue

```
<t ...some code...

   <td t-if="o.sale_id">
                      <span t-field="pack_operation.price"/>    I want to have this only once in my table  
  </td>

</t>
```

Is it even possible???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean `pack_operation` is a recordset of multiple records and you need the total sum, you can use

```
<span><t t-esc="sum(pack_operation.mapped('price'))" /></span>
```